# What would be the effects of a worldwide nuclear disaster?

Tags: post-apocalypse, nuclear

I have a dystopian project coming up and I would like to ask for some advice. What would be the effects of a worldwide nuclear disaster? Some answers to include are:

1. How long until humans would be able to inhabit earth again?
2. Would anyone be safe?
3. What would happen to agriculture? Vegetation?
4. Would mutations occur? If so, what type?
5. How would this effect society?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! You may want to take the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) in order to become acquainted with the purpose and rules of this site. In particular, this site doesn't like multiple questions in one post. And then, this site requires clear questions, so that they can receive clear answers. For example, what is a *"worldwide nuclear disaster"*? What makes you believe that humans won't be able to inhabit Earth after such an event? How can anybody be safe (question 2) when the entire Earth is inhabitable (question 1)? What is a mutation "type" (question 4)?

Comment: Too many questions in one, and not enough information to answer properly. Somebody wrote an entire book just to answer some of these questions you posted here.

Comment: 4 yes, Mutation = cancer

Comment: It would help if you would explain just what your "worldwide nuclear disaster" is supposed to do.  AFAIK, no such disaster, nor even a full-scale nuclear war, could render the entire Earth uninhabitable.

Comment: "How would X affect society?" is almost universally considered "too broad" on Worldbuilding SE on its own, and that's just *one* of your *eight* questions. You'll need to narrow this down to focus on a specific aspect that you're interested in, *and* flesh it out with more details; for example, as jamesqf mentioned, what that disaster is about. There's also a massive difference between habitable and safe... for example, the area around Chernobyl is plenty habitable (lots of wildlife in the area proves it), but it isn't necessarily safe.

Comment: I'm adding my vote to put this on hold, but if you [Edit] during the "on hold" grace period, it will automatically be nominated for community review for reopening.

Comment: This isn't a bad question per-se, we just need to narrow the focus.  Let's get rid of some of the questions that have common answers.  (1) The world is basically radiation-free in 10 years or less, but that doesn't mean inhabitable (a lot of things are dead, after all).  (4) X-men style mutations are pure fantasy.  Radiation kills.  As VIncent says, the only mutation is cancer, and it would be common.  For (3) look into the [Tunguska event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event) and [Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster).  To answer (2&5) we need lots more detail.